# Как вывести значение из БД

Tags: mysql, golang

Как вывести значение из БД при помощи Golang mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы работать с mysql (или другой базой данных) нужно импортировать драйвер нужной базы, а для собственно работы с базой пользоваться пакетом database/sql.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/database")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error()) // Just for example purpose. You should use proper error handling instead of panic
    }
    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age = $1", age)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for rows.Next() {
        var name string
        if err := rows.Scan(&name); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s is %d\n", name, age)
    }
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```